# How to get full job name from HPC cluster

Tags: powershell, hpc

I need to get job name from HPC culster. 
I'm running this command through powershell:

```
Hpc>powershell -command "& {&'Add-PSSnapIn' Microsoft.HPC}"; "& {&'Get-HpcJob' -Scheduler il-winhpc4}"
```

I get the list, but no matter what I do  - Name is only number of characters long, not full name. 
Any ideas?

```
Id       Name       State           Owner                Priority        NumberOfTask                                                              s
--       ----       -----           -----                --------        ------------
5323613  Deploy ... Running         WINHPC4\tfsbuild                     30
5323614  Deploy ... Running         WINHPC4\tfsbuild                     30
5323643  Deploy ... Running         WINHPC4\tfsbuild                     30
```

Comment: What if you add `| Format-Table -AutoSize` to the last command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in detail here: https://poshoholic.com/2010/11/11/powershell-quick-tip-creating-wide-tables-with-powershell/ , the PowerShell output formatters are trying to take your output and fit on the console for you to read.

You have three main options for changing this; `Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width nnnn`, `Format-List`, or `ConvertTo-Json`:

Out-String:

```
powershell -command "Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.HPC; Get-HpcJob -Scheduler il-winhpc4 | Format-Table -Auto | Out-String -Width 4000"

# The same kind of table you have, but with horizontal scrolling.
```

Format-List:

```
powershell -command "Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.HPC; Get-HpcJob -Scheduler il-winhpc4 | Format-List"

Id: 5323613
Name: Deploy thing to place
State: running
```

ConvertTo-Json (or other machine-readable format like XML):

```
powershell -command "Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.HPC; Get-HpcJob -Scheduler il-winhpc4 | ConvertTo-Json"

[
    {
        "Id": 5323613,
        "Name": "Deploy thing to place",
        "State": "Running"
    },
    ..
]
```

That's assuming you want all the other information. If you don't, maybe you could just do:

```
powershell -command "Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.HPC; Get-HpcJob -Scheduler il-winhpc4 | Select-Object Id, Name"
```

or

```
powershell -command "Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.HPC; Get-HpcJob -Scheduler il-winhpc4 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name"
```

NB. You don't need anything like as many `&{&'';&{&'` as you have. You don't need any at all, I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot. All the examples you provided work great. Looks like I have a bit of powershell reading to do :)